# Mercurial central repository LAN ghost folder?

Tags: macos, windows-7, mercurial, samba, lan

I'm working on setting up version control on a company LAN using the setup described in this [tutorial](http://hginit.com/02.html)

The central repository is located on a Mac OS, with the developers running either Windows or Mac OS. Pushing and pulling from the central repository to a local repository on both Windows and Mac OS works.

What I can't understand is that the central repository folder appears duplicated in Windows Explorer ('CentralRepo' and 'CentralRepo-1'), yet when logged in as admin on the Mac OS hosting the central repository, this folder cannot be located. The duplicated folder can only be seen on one particular Windows computer.

Is it a temp folder? Is there anything that can be done to remove this duplicated folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with Mercurial. It's just some Windows or Samba screwiness. Because of the nature of a DVCS, you should never need to use Explorer to view the remote repo, so just ignore it.